# Why isn't this unique Laravel validation working?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

I've been scouring the internet and laravel docs trying to get this working.

Ideally, I can just use the $request->validate() method. But I've also tried manually making and reporting the errors too (which got me a little closer, but still didn't work everywhere I needed it to).

Here's my situation.

Somebody creates a post. They create a title, and I generate a slug based on that title.

The titles have to be unique. This is working as expected. I always get sent back with a nice error message that the title must be unique.

The slug must be unique too. This could be a problem if someone named a post `hello`, and then named another post `hello!`

```html
<form ...>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
</form>
```

So they submit, and in my controller method, before I do any validation, I add the slug to the request.

```php
$request->slug = Str::slug($request->title);
```

Then I try the validation

```php
$request->validate([
  'title' => 'required|unique:posts',
  'slug' => 'unique:posts,slug'
]);
```

In situations like `Post-1` and `Post 1` or `hello` and `hello!` I expect the validation to fail for the slug the same way it has for the title.

But instead, it doesn't, and then I get an SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'post-1' for key 'posts.posts_slug_unique'
```

I got it working with `Validator::make`... But only for the store method. It still didn't work on updates. Also, it wasn't nearly as clean.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's generally considered an anti-pattern in Laravel to add things to the request object. Anyway, if you really gotta do it, the correct way is to do `$request->request->add(['slug', Str::slug($request->title)]);`

Comment: If I wanted to validate that slug (even though it's not part of the request), what do you suggest as a best practice? If I can do it in a better way, then I'd prefer that.

Comment: Actually, I've got several ideas for better ways to do it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@uz4ir had the fix for me.

It may not be the best-practice solution, but there are plans for adding custom slug inputs to the form in the future. So this code will be removed in the future.

Other solutions I looked at seemed to be a lot more effort, and I couldn't see any harm in adding the slug to the request at this point.

Changing

```php
$request->slug = Str::slug($request->title);
```

to

```php
$request->request->add(['slug' => Str::slug($request->title)]);
```

works great.